# Gmail API: filter, edit and then forward an email

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Is it possible to create a filter for a certain email, to automate an edit of the email's content and then forward to a list of addresses?

Comment: is it possible for you to show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Explore this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/#typical_use_cases) to help you started.

> The Gmail API is a RESTful API that can be used to access Gmail
>   mailboxes and send mail. For most web applications (including mobile
>   apps), the Gmail API is the best choice for authorized access to a
>   user's Gmail data.
>
> The Gmail API gives you flexible, RESTful access to the user's inbox,
>   with a natural interface to [`Threads`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads), [`Messages`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages), [`Labels`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels), [`Drafts`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts),
>   [`History`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history), and. [`Settings`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings). From the modern language of your choice, your
>   app can use the API to add Gmail features like:
>
> - Read messages from Gmail
> - Send email messages
> - Modify the labels applied to messages and threads
> - Search for specific messages and threads
> - Create filters to automatically label, forward, or archive messages